# Mouse move and thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, macos, mono, mouse

When I move the mouse over the window, the program runs much faster (cc. 3 times). This is a real time webcam .Net/Mono application running on a MacBook. On Windows works perfectly. Is this maybe a power saving function of the laptop? The code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(Foo);
t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest; // I've tried without priority too, doesn't matter
t.Start();
...
delegate void SetInt(int k);
void Foo()
{
    int k = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        ++k; 
        BeginInvoke(new SetInt(Bar), k);   
    }
}
void Bar(int k)
{
    Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image).DrawString(k.ToString(),
        System.Fonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Red, 0, 0);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

I watch the value of k. It is incremented 10-30 times a sec, depending on the mouse movement. It looks like the UI thread blocks the worker thread? The worker thread should increment k million times in a sec.

**Edit:** Miguel de Icaza suspects this is a bug in Mono. I uploaded it to Mono's bugtracker:
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=663433
Test case is attached. Now I'm searching for a hack to avoid the problem.

Comment: "the program runs faster" - how measured? do you mean you get more frequent UI updates?

Comment: I watch the value of k. Maybe not faster just the thread more frequently active? Moreover this thread is not the UI, it's a new working thread.

Answer (score 2):

Different OS's treat thread priority differently, and you cannot depend on them working the same way on different OS's.  You can't even depend on them working the same way across different Virtual Machines (Mono vs .net), because these are OS dependant values and not really defined by the specification.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this, and believe I have found a workaround.  I had the same issue with a program in C# .Net running on Mono where messages weren't being processed in a thread.  It seems the issue is with the thread not getting invoked or waiting for an event.  The work around I found is as follows.

1) Create a form event (note it is different to System.Timers)

`private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timerForMonoResponsiveness;`

2) Set up the form event in the Constructor or Initialization

```
// This is a fix for mono not updating messages until an event (such as movement of
// the mouse) happens
// We use an event timer to fire off an event on a regular basis.
// This calls a function that doesn't do anything.
if (Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null) // Only run if in Mono
{
    this.timerForMonoResponsiveness = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
    this.timerForMonoResponsiveness.Interval = 100;
    this.timerForMonoResponsiveness.Tick += new EventHandler(timertimerForMonoResponsiveness_Tick);
    this.timerForMonoResponsiveness.Start();
}
```

NOTE: the "**this.components**" is defined in the **Form.designer.cs** of the form (should be done automatically) mine looks like this:

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

It is initialized as:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
```

3) Create the tick function for the timer

```
// This function executes a Tick event so the UI updates on Mono
// This is a Mono bug workaround as the message processing was not being processed
// and was waiting on invoke which on Mono only runs when a UI element is changed (or  
// the mouse is moved). This function therefore runs regularly to mitigate this issue 
// it is called within a Mono check and will not run on Windows
// The function is SUPPOSED TO DO NOTHING.

private void timerForMonoResponsiveness_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timerMonoEventForMessagesToBeUpdated.Stop();
    // This doesn't need to do anything, just call the event
    this.timerMonoEventForMessagesToBeUpdated.Start();          
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Considering youre running this on Mono on a mac, i'm thinking the CLR isn't getting full priority or the thread isnt getting full priority. Here I agree with mystere man, your Priority statement may not be having the desired effect.

Also Windows 7 seems to optimize foreground processes to give them a higher priority so the UI seems more responsive, and the mac OS may be doing that a little too much. Therefore when activity occurs in your application (mouse movements and maybe keyboard presses) your application is given more processor time..

Could be Mono is not handling the priority or somethign is changing your priority during runtime (the OS iteself).